# How to pick assign something to something out of 2 in C?

Tags: c, random, struct, probability

so i have got a struct that goes:

```
enum input_result get_human_player(struct player* human)
{
    char playerName[NAMELEN];
    printf("What is your name? ");
    fgets(playerName, NAMELEN, stdin);
    strcpy((*human).name, playerName);

    (*human).type = HUMAN;
    (*human).thiscolor = C_WHITE;
    (*human).counters = 0;

    return FAILURE;
}
```

how do i make it so it randomly assigns it to either C_WHITE or C_RED with a 50/50 chance?

Comment: Do you know how to generate randomly one out of two numbers (say `0` or `1`)?

Comment: using the rand() function?

Comment: Note: do not write something like `(*human).name`. Use the arow operator `humans->name`.

Comment: @SadJavaBoi: `rand` does not guarantee a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` will return a random integer. Assuming it is uniformly distributed (which might not be true, as not guaranteed by every implementation), the number will be  odd or even with 50/50 chance. Using this fact:

```
if (rand() % 2)
{
    //Do the first thing
}
else
{
    // Do the other one
}
```

** Don't forget to seed the random number generator.

Comment: Thanks, that was all I needed. +1